# Can't load the dataset from sklearn.datasets

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

I've working on this dataset for the last 2 weeks. It was working fine till today when I tried to run it again. It said that the dataset was not found. Does anyone know what's the problems?

```
#load dataset
mnist = fetch_openml('Fashion-MNIST', version=1, cache=True)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-21686811829f> in <module>()
      1 #load dataset
----> 2 mnist = fetch_openml('Fashion-MNIST', version=1, cache=True)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/datasets/_openml.py in _get_json_content_from_openml_api(url, error_message, raise_if_error, data_home)
    166     # 412 error, not in except for nicer traceback
    167     if raise_if_error:
--> 168         raise ValueError(error_message)
    169     return None
    170 

ValueError: Dataset with data_id 40996 not found.
```

Comment: I got the same error, even tho if you search here https://www.openml.org/api_docs#!/data/get_data_id with the id 40996, the dataset exist! might be a problem in the servers? I updated to scikit-learn-0.22.1 and the problem persists

Comment: I used the same sklearn version too. It worked perfectly last night tho. I found out that people download the csv file and run it instead of load directly from sklearn. Hopefully, it is a head up that helps you too.